# How can I use my data model in my Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to this so I do apologize. But I created a Firebase Firestore data model to represent my article post from Firestore. When I type it into the AppBar's title section, I am getting an error. How do you work with this? I would appreciate any sort of help or hints as I am new to this so I am still learning. I have also downloaded all the required dependencies for this.

[My Firestore database screen in case if this is also needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w4Te.png)

This is my Post model which models my articles from my Firestore database.

```
class Post {

String title;
  String imageURL;
  String text;



Post({this.title, this.imageURL, this.text});

  factory Post.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    var data = doc.data();

return Post(
  title: data['title'],
  imageURL: data['imageURL'],
  text: data['text']
);
  }

}
```

This is my article page (ReaderPage)

```
// This page displays article to the user.
class ReaderPage extends StatelessWidget {

  CollectionReference posts = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    // This line is causing errors...
    title: Post.fromFirestore().title,
  ),
  body: Container(

  ),
);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not reading the value from the Firestore. Refer: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#read-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is correct, but you are not reading from Firestore.
You could use a FutureBuilder to build the content only when the promise given by the firestore query has been resolved:

```
return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: posts.doc(documentId).get(),
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Something went wrong");
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
      return return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: data.title,
      ),
      body: Container(

      ),
    );
    }

    return Text("loading");
  },
);
```

But in this way you are not using the model you have created.

In my opinion the best way could be implement a DatabaseService class:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'posts.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  /// Get a stream of a single document
  Stream<Post> streamPost(String uid) {
    return _db
        .collection('posts')
        .document(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snap) => Post.fromFirestore(snap.data));
  }

  /// Query a subcollection
  Stream<List<Post>> streamPost(String uid) {
    var ref = _db.collection('posts');

    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
    
  }

}
```

But in this way you have to work with streams.
I suggest you to have a look at this library: [Flutter Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)
And this article could help you: [Here](https://fireship.io/lessons/advanced-flutter-firebase/)

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try this out! :)

Comment: Hey can you please provide a documentation or resource where I can learn about how to create models and how to use them. I'm really stuck at it. I can use providers, streamBuilders but I didn't understand about models.